# how do i stay on the same tab after post back

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

View Profile

Edit Profile

<--I would like to stay on the same tab after post back i am using metro 4 framework tab control-->

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Consider using Ajax instead of a full postback. (P.s. Given the almost total lack of information given in the question, that's about as specific an answer as you're likely to get, I would think.)